# changing language at disqus comments script

Tags: javascript, translation, disqus

I want to use disqus comments script (disqus.com) with arabic language
I added this code to my webpage

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var disqus_config = function () { 
  this.language = "ar";
};
</script>
```

but it didn't converted to arabic !
please help.

Comment: Any errors in the console? Also, 9 of your 11 questions have answers. You should accept them if they solve your problem. People will be more likely to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just go to admin/settings (diqus portal), and then in the tab General disable  the checkbox with the label "Enable Disqus 2012 features for your site" save the updates and that's it.

It appears that the language package is not working well for the last version.

Comment: This answer does not seem to be valid in 2016 anymore. "Enable Disqus 2012 feature for your site" is nowhere to be found in the admin panel.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WordPress, you can install the plugin [Disqus Language](https://wordpress.org/plugins/disqus-language/) which will automatically detect the page language and display Disqus in that language, one major benefit is that it's a server solution, i.e no JavaScript is added on the front end.